# AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`timestamp`' given input columns: [date_trunc(hour, timestamp)];

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a table like below

```
| job_id| timestamp                      | avg_Tag_value |
|:----  |:------------------------------- | ------------- |
| j1    | 2023-03-19T01:52:00.000+0000    | 0.4           |
| j2    | 2023-03-19T01:53:00.000+0000    | 0.5           |
| j3    | 2023-03-19T01:54:00.000+0000    | 0.6           |
```

and I want to truncate the timestamp to hour using df = df.select(date_trunc("hour", "timestamp"))

and I'm getting an error like "AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`timestamp`' given input columns: [date_trunc(hour, timestamp)];"

timestamp column is timestamp type. not sure what's causing the error..

Anyone can help with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me (I'm guessing you haven't imported functions module `pyspark.sql.functions`) -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# Create the input DataFrame
data = [("j1", "2023-03-19T01:52:00.000+0000", 0.4),
        ("j2", "2023-03-19T01:53:00.000+0000", 0.5),
        ("j3", "2023-03-19T01:54:00.000+0000", 0.6)]

schema = ["job_id", "timestamp", "avg_Tag_value"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df = df.select(date_trunc("hour", "timestamp"))

df.show(truncate=False)

+---------------------------+
|date_trunc(hour, timestamp)|
+---------------------------+
|        2023-03-19 01:00:00|
|        2023-03-19 01:00:00|
|        2023-03-19 01:00:00|
+---------------------------+
```

[image: Image for details]

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce same thing in my environment. I got this similar error.

[image]

**To resolve this issue. Please follow this code:**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_trunc, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, TimestampType, DoubleType

sch1 = StructType([
    StructField("job_id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("timestamp", StringType(), True),
    StructField("avg_Tag_value", DoubleType(), True)
])
d1 = [
    ("j1", "2023-03-19T01:52:00.000+0000", 0.4),
    ("j2", "2023-03-19T01:53:00.000+0000", 0.5),
    ("j3", "2023-03-19T01:54:00.000+0000", 0.6)
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(d1, sch1)
df = df.select(date_trunc("hour", col("timestamp")).alias("hour"), "avg_Tag_value")

df.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]
[image]